# How to insert coding and Maths formula into database

Tags: sql-server, html, math

I am working on a project which contains the question with options and solution of that question. I want to display the Mats equations and some coding questions on webpage. So my query is what will the the procedure to insert those equation into Database and display it on my webpage.
for the reference I want to display like this following link :

http://www.indiabix.com/aptitude/compound-interest/

http://www.indiabix.com/c-programming/functions/

Thanks

Comment: what effort do you have put in until now ??

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking as far as I understood your problem you do not have Idea about coding (I may be wrong but as you are not suggesting any particular database and any technical stuff I'm assuming this.)

You can use prebuilt frameworks for this job you don't need to design application from scratch unless it is your some project.

Some suggested Links are this ...

[Moodle](https://moodle.org)

[WordPress](http://www.wordpress.org)

You need to find plugin after installing these frameworks on your webserver bundle 
For that you can use 
[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en) on windows or LAMP if on Linux

But Again your question too general. Give some inputs first

Information About Moodle:
IF you go throught moodle webiste you will get to know that how powerful LMS( learning management system ).

You just need to know how to configure such websites 
Go through this [video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KH2BvLG22W0) if you want to

Infromation About WordPress: 
Wordpress is general purpose Website so you can develop any service with it very easily and everything including database is taken care by it (same case with moodle but moodle is more focused on LMS )
You have to search for LMS plugin inside wordpress for your purpose.

KINDLY ACCEPT THIS ONE AS ANsWER if you find information usefule... (Points help me contribute more and allows me also to ask question)

Comment: Nop. You don't need to create any such thing ... 
There are readymade things available ... opensource .. for this job and you don't need to code a single line for this ..

Comment: Yea Sure....Tonight around 9.30 will be okay for you ..According to indian timings..

Comment: Thanks ,,, see you then

Comment: Hi, can you share your id please.

Comment: I reallly am sorry that i couln't come onliine ....I was stuck in work like anythin ,,,,
IF you okay ,,can we come online tomorrow...
My id is spt025 same as so ...